# Highest known minimum bipartite crossing number?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, np-complete

I'd like to know what the highest known complete bipartite minimum crossing number graph K is? Last I knew it was K 7,7 , has K 8,8 been conjectured or proven yet?

Any info on where I could find proofs and conjectures on bipartite minimum crossing numbers would be nice.

Comment: For conjecture about the crossing number, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZarankiewiczsConjecture.html